# why does matplotlib FuncAnimation init_func not work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have some trouble getting init_func in FuncAnimation to work, meaning the artists return by init_func are not drawn. I want to use it to set the background for the animation instead of passing the background each frame, because my animation is getting really slow (does that even matter?).

My code:

```
def _create_animation(self, steps=None, **kwargs):

    def static_artists():  # TODO: why doesnt init_func work???
        return self.static_artists

    def dynamic_artists(items):
        return self.get_dynamic_artists(items)

    def yield_from_grid():
        yield from self.grid.generate(**kwargs)

    self.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure,
                                             func=dynamic_artists,
                                             frames=yield_from_grid,
                                             init_func=static_artists,
                                             interval=25,
                                             save_count=steps,
                                             blit=False)
    plt.show()
```

It works if i just do:

```
def _create_animation(self, steps=None, **kwargs):

    def dynamic_artists(items):
        return self.static_artists + self.get_dynamic_artists(items)  # just add static items every frame

    def yield_from_grid():
        yield from self.grid.generate(**kwargs)

    self.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure,
                                             func=dynamic_artists,
                                             frames=yield_from_grid,
                                             interval=25,
                                             save_count=steps,
                                             blit=False)
    plt.show()
```

But what is then the point of init_func?

Comment: The function supplied to `init_func` is executed at the start of the animation. One cannot know what fails for you without [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : that is not that easy in this case, i was hoping that someone would know why conceptually the first piece of code might not work, given the second piece does work (since all the artists involved are the same, the configs are the same, etc.)

Comment: One would not expect any difference between the two codes; but of course without a [mcve], just anything can happen.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: tried to reproduce in an isolated example, but failed. Also in the latest version it works as excepted (no idea why), so i guess the question is moot by now.